# Asterisk pattern matching

Tags: regex, asterisk

I'm running Asterisk 11.4.0 under Fedora. I've got 3 external lines: A, B and C. I need to make a dial rule in my extensions.conf:
If the call is going to @u-tel.com - use A;
If the call is going to simple numeric phones like 911 - use B;
In any other situation (call goes to sip account, which is not from u-tel.com, use C);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pattern matching can be done with other languages like java,PHP. Asteriks support these languages.
Here is a tutorial for asterisk-java http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html
I think it can be done with AMI.

Comment: yes,  pattern matching can be in Asterisk , Here is a link to the subject http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449332426/asterisk-DP-Basics.html , find Pattern matching topic on that page. Its easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, this book describes everything I asked about.